# Split strings of different lengths and paste in specific column in a dataframe based on match

Tags: r, dataframe, strsplit

I have a vector that has strings of different lengths:
The vector looks like the example below:

```
TX <- c("d_Bacteria|g_Thermobaculum", "d_Bacteria|p_Acidobacteria|c_Acidobacteria subdivision|f_Vicinamibacteraceae|g_Luteitalea", "d_Bacteria|p_Acidobacteria|c_Acidobacteriia|o_Acidobacteriales|f_Acidobacteriaceae|g_Acidobacterium", "d_Bacteria|p_Acidobacteria|c_Acidobacteriia|o_Acidobacteriales|f_Acidobacteriaceae|g_Candidatus Koribacter", "d_Bacteria|p_Acidobacteria|c_Acidobacteriia|o_Acidobacteriales|f_Acidobacteriaceae|g_Granulicella", "d_Bacteria|p_Acidobacteria|c_Acidobacteriia|o_Acidobacteriales|f_Acidobacteriaceae|g_Terriglobus")
```

I need to make a data frame to divide each string according to taxonomic annotation: "domain","phylum","class","order","family","genus"

I tried:

```
taxon <- str_split(clade_names, "\\|", simplify = T)
```

It works for splitting it perfectly, but it fills up the data frame from left to right and I need it to be filled according to taxonomic level.

I believe I would need to use `grepl` to match "d_","p_", "c_", "o_", "f_", "g_"
But I am not managing to figure out how to write it correctly.

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: two slightly hacky solution ideas: 1. after str_splitting, you coudl just do a few if_else commands to mutate new variables so sth. like "if_else(value starts with p_, then variable p_ ... is value, otherwise NA)"

Comment: 2. idea: after str_splitting, you could pivoting longer the data set change the value of the created "name" column based on the values and then reshape it back with pivot_wider.

Comment: Also, it would be great if you could provide a minimal reproducible example that we can work with, not only a copied output. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I uptade with code parts of what I did, so one can reproduce it. =)

Comment: You could use `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package, splitting twice. `library(splitstackshape); cSplit(cSplit(as.data.table(TX)[, row := seq_along(TX)], "TX", "|", "long"), "TX", "_", "wide")[, dcast(.SD, row ~ TX_1, value.var="TX_2")]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using *data.table*, split on `"|"`, reshape wide-to-long, then split on `"_"` to get taxonomic annotation group, then reshape long-to-wide:

```
library(data.table)

TX <- c("d_Bacteria|g_Thermobaculum", "d_Bacteria|p_Acidobacteria|c_Acidobacteria subdivision|f_Vicinamibacteraceae|g_Luteitalea", "d_Bacteria|p_Acidobacteria|c_Acidobacteriia|o_Acidobacteriales|f_Acidobacteriaceae|g_Acidobacterium", "d_Bacteria|p_Acidobacteria|c_Acidobacteriia|o_Acidobacteriales|f_Acidobacteriaceae|g_Candidatus Koribacter", "d_Bacteria|p_Acidobacteria|c_Acidobacteriia|o_Acidobacteriales|f_Acidobacteriaceae|g_Granulicella", "d_Bacteria|p_Acidobacteria|c_Acidobacteriia|o_Acidobacteriales|f_Acidobacteriaceae|g_Terriglobus")

taxon <- data.table(x = TX)

taxon[, tstrsplit(x, "|", fixed = TRUE)
      ][, rn := seq_len(.N)
        ][, melt(.SD, id.var = "rn")
          ][, c("grp", "name") := tstrsplit(value, "_")
            ][!is.na(value), dcast(.SD, rn ~ grp, value.var = "value")]
#    rn                           c          d                     f                       g                  o               p
# 1:  1                        <NA> d_Bacteria                  <NA>         g_Thermobaculum               <NA>            <NA>
# 2:  2 c_Acidobacteria subdivision d_Bacteria f_Vicinamibacteraceae            g_Luteitalea               <NA> p_Acidobacteria
# 3:  3            c_Acidobacteriia d_Bacteria   f_Acidobacteriaceae        g_Acidobacterium o_Acidobacteriales p_Acidobacteria
# 4:  4            c_Acidobacteriia d_Bacteria   f_Acidobacteriaceae g_Candidatus Koribacter o_Acidobacteriales p_Acidobacteria
# 5:  5            c_Acidobacteriia d_Bacteria   f_Acidobacteriaceae          g_Granulicella o_Acidobacteriales p_Acidobacteria
# 6:  6            c_Acidobacteriia d_Bacteria   f_Acidobacteriaceae           g_Terriglobus o_Acidobacteriales p_Acidobacteria
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tidyverse solution (which i guess you prefer, since you are using the str_split function already):

```
library(tidyverse)
TX <- data.frame(clade_names = c("d_Bacteria|g_Thermobaculum", "d_Bacteria|p_Acidobacteria|c_Acidobacteria subdivision|f_Vicinamibacteraceae|g_Luteitalea", "d_Bacteria|p_Acidobacteria|c_Acidobacteriia|o_Acidobacteriales|f_Acidobacteriaceae|g_Acidobacterium", "d_Bacteria|p_Acidobacteria|c_Acidobacteriia|o_Acidobacteriales|f_Acidobacteriaceae|g_Candidatus Koribacter", "d_Bacteria|p_Acidobacteria|c_Acidobacteriia|o_Acidobacteriales|f_Acidobacteriaceae|g_Granulicella", "d_Bacteria|p_Acidobacteria|c_Acidobacteriia|o_Acidobacteriales|f_Acidobacteriaceae|g_Terriglobus"))

TX2 <- TX %>%
  mutate(splits = str_split(clade_names, "\\|")) %>%
  unnest_wider(splits) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -clade_names) %>%
  mutate(name = str_sub(value, 1, 2)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(name)) %>%
  pivot_wider()
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 7
  clade_names                                        d_       g_           p_        c_            f_          o_        
  <chr>                                              <chr>    <chr>        <chr>     <chr>         <chr>       <chr>     
1 d_Bacteria|g_Thermobaculum                         d_Bacte~ g_Thermobac~ NA        NA            NA          NA        
2 d_Bacteria|p_Acidobacteria|c_Acidobacteria subdiv~ d_Bacte~ g_Luteitalea p_Acidob~ c_Acidobacte~ f_Vicinami~ NA        
3 d_Bacteria|p_Acidobacteria|c_Acidobacteriia|o_Aci~ d_Bacte~ g_Acidobact~ p_Acidob~ c_Acidobacte~ f_Acidobac~ o_Acidoba~
4 d_Bacteria|p_Acidobacteria|c_Acidobacteriia|o_Aci~ d_Bacte~ g_Candidatu~ p_Acidob~ c_Acidobacte~ f_Acidobac~ o_Acidoba~
5 d_Bacteria|p_Acidobacteria|c_Acidobacteriia|o_Aci~ d_Bacte~ g_Granulice~ p_Acidob~ c_Acidobacte~ f_Acidobac~ o_Acidoba~
6 d_Bacteria|p_Acidobacteria|c_Acidobacteriia|o_Aci~ d_Bacte~ g_Terriglob~ p_Acidob~ c_Acidobacte~ f_Acidobac~ o_Acidoba~
```

You could of course tune this code further to provide more meaningful names or to delete the X_ part from the clade_names etc.